# Cygwin gitk issue

Tags: git, bash, cygwin, x11, gitk

I have recently installed all of the X11 packages in the cygwin setup and now
have is massive annoying error with not being able to see gitk. Everything was
working perfectly well until I installed this stuff.

Before I had this issue I didn't really note done any of the configuration I
merely started xwinserver went to my branch and typed gitk and everything
appeared.
Now I have to put in my display as it claims the display is not set. I export my
display settings check that it is set properly by running xclock which does
appear. Then I get the issue:

```
1 [main] wish8.5 3436 child_info_fork::abort: data segment start: parent(0x4CF000) != child(0x67F000)
Error in startup script: unknown color name "SystemButtonFace"
while executing
"winfo rgb . $c"
(procedure "setui" line 3)
invoked from within
"setui $uicolor"
(file "C:\cygwin\bin\gitk" line 11504)
```

Not got a clue what this is. I have seen a couple of relevant questions but no
answers.

Notes: I am using Windows 7 64 bit and using a Bash shell

Update: I am still getting exactly the same error. This is really frustrating! I
may just download Debian

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was able to get gitk working as of today with the following versions on Win 7 64 Bit :

```
$ cygcheck -c cygwin git gitk tcl tcl-tk
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
cygwin               1.7.10-1       OK
git                  1.7.9-1        OK
gitk                 1.7.9-1        OK
tcl                  8.5.11-1       OK
tcl-tk               8.5.11-1       OK
```

The most valuable link was the one posted by aap. That led me to all the other steps.

To fix the fork failures follow [this](http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures) link from Cygwin FAQ. 
The steps I followed were as follows:

1. Start -> Run -> ash.exe -> **/bin/rebaseall**  (There was no output when I ran that command)
2. One of the reasons why you might get fork failures is the presence of Antivirus/Firewall/Spyware-cleaner softwares. 

   In my case the [BLODA](http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.bloda) softwares listed as reasons for the fork failures was McAfee which I have on my work pc. The fix was to move the Cygwin directory inside a folder excluded by McAfee's OAS and create a symbolic link to the old location like so:

   `mklink /D C:\Cygwin C:\Dev\Cygwin`


   **C:\Dev** is the excluded folder
   The folder exclusions can be configured using the Viruscan Console. To test whether your current Cygwin directory is excluded see [this](https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB59742).
3. **Starting GITK**

   - **Method 1**

     1. In Cygwin Console : 
         `startx&`
     2. The title of the window that pops up must be used to set the DISPLAY env variable in Cygwin like so:

        Title : **Cygwin/X:1.0**, then do `export DISPLAY=localhost:1.0`

        Title : **Cygwin/X:0.0**, then do `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0`
     3. Finally start gitk like so : 
        `gitk&`
     4. What I ended up with was this : 


            [image]
   - **Method 2**

     1. Create a file **~/.startxwinrc** with the following contents:

        `gitk&`
     2. Then run the following command:

        **startxwin >/dev/null 2>&1**
     3. I ended up with a gitk window which looks exactly like the one before the whole 'require X' thing mentioned by aap happened :


            [image]

Comment: That needs to be /bin/rebaseall -- the full path is required when in the ash shell.

Comment: Thanks David. I have changed the post to use the absolute path.

Comment: I have followed all these steps and still have the same issue. The only difference is I have a different version of git and gitk

Comment: Quick question user700786 ... Did you try deleting ~/.gitk as aap suggests before starting Gitk ?

Comment: As stated below this has not solved my issue, however, I think it will solve a lot of other peoples issues as it solved 2/3 of mine with EXCELLENT discription

Answer (score 17):

Seems there are three issues here.

1. DISPLAY requirement is due to Cygwin Tk changing to [require X](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2012-02/msg00011.html).
2. SystemButtonFace error is also due to the same change. The recommended fix is to [remove your ~/.gitk](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-02/msg00288.html) settings file, or at least the line in that file referencing SystemButtonFace.
3. fork issue -- seems to require [rebaseall](http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Rebaseall).

Note also that there is an updated version 1.7.9 of git and gitk finding its way to the cygwin mirrors, but by itself that version did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks, removing the .gitk file fixed it for me.

Comment: .gitk removal work for a developer here that was getting the same problem as well.

Comment: For the sake of anyone still experiencing this after following this answer, your gitk configs might be read from ~/.config/git/gitk rather than .gitk, so you'd need to remove that file instead.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the above answer, I did a different fix. In my `~/.bash_profile`, I added the following:

```
startxwin >/dev/null 2>&1
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
```

I think that's a better solution than adding gitk& to the ~/.startxwinrc, since then it only works with gitk. This way you can then do git gui and other things as well.

Comment: If you happen to work with multiple terminals I recommend adding a condition like `ps | grep -q /usr/bin/XWin || startxwin`

Answer (score 4):

The other answers suggesting to remove ~/.gitk pointed in the right direction, but in new releases the config file is in ~/.config/git/gitk by default, as pointed by [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitk#_files).

Answer (score 3):

The solutions everyone else is posting are relating to [Tcl/Tk's new reliance on X11](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-02/msg00115.html). Actually, the error you're seeing is a follow-on error due to having run gitk under GDI before the X11 requirement came along.

[The fix](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-02/msg00660.html) is to edit your `~/.gitk` file, and delete any lines that refer to `SystemButtonFace`. Once you've done that, everything should Just Work™ again.

Comment: If you don't care about your gitk configuration, I found it easier to just move or delete the ~/.gitk file. gitk will generate a new config file with the default settings, which should not throw this error message anymore. "mv ~/.gitk ~/.gitk-backup"

Comment: For the sake of anyone still experiencing this after following this answer, your gitk configs might be read from ~/.config/git/gitk rather than .gitk, so you'd need to remove that file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on bender's answer

- Install xinit package
- Go go `C:\cygwin\bin`, double click `ash.exe`
- enter `./rebaseall`

Then you can start `gitk` with

```
startxwin
gitk
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error.  The issue was that I initially used [git bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) and later switched to using git in [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/).

Git bash's gitk had created a ~/.gitk file that was incompatible with cygwin's tcl/tk.  If you delete ~/.gitk, when you run cygwin's gitk it will create a new file.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to remove cygwin and re-install it. The issue lies somewhere in the X11 for me. When I re-installed I had to rebaseall as I had a fork issue so these answers really helped. I did have to set the display as well so that is going in my .bashrc

I'm sorry that I can not provide something more concrete, however, whatever I tried my same issue kept reappearing.