# What do I need to do to fix the screen refresh issue on XWin (Cygwin)?

Tags: graphics, cygwin, refresh, git-gui, gitk

I was getting an following error starting gitk/git gui so I installed xinit as per the stackoverflow solution.

```
application-specific initialization failed: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

so now I start XWin as `XWin &`

and then used `export DISPLAY=:0.0` and then started the `gitk &`/`git gui &`.

But now I get screen paint issue. The screen does not refresh in XWin, when I hover my mouse over the contents of the screen the contents under the mouse pointer gets refreshed but it is very difficult to get it display the full screen contents refreshed.

What am I doing wrong? or what do I need to do to fix the screen refresh issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248034/cygwin-gitk-issue). All I had to do was to start the xwin as `startxwin &`

Comment: that is the suggested default https://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html#using-starting